# Fixed-point Theorem Problem

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

Show that the sequence generated by the formula
xn+1 =(2/3)*xn +a/(3xn^2) (n = 0, 1, 2, . . .)
converges to a^1/3 for any x0 > 0.
[Hint: first, use the fixed-point theorem to show that xn → a^1/3 whenever x0 > a^1/3, then show that if 0 < x0 < a^1/3, then x1 > a^1/3.]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given sequence $x_(n+1)$ $=$ $(2/3)$$x_n$ $+$ $a/3$($x_n$)² 
As you have told to use **fixed-point theorem**

So consider the given sequence to be a function "$\phi$"
   Gives as $\phi(x)$ $=$ $2/3$$x$ $+$ $a/3x²$

By definition of fix point , **if $x$ is a fixed point then  $\phi(x)$$=$$x$**

Thus ,  $2/3$$x$ $+$ $a/3x²$ $=$ $x$

$a/3x²$$=$ $x/3$

$x³$$=$$a$

$x$$=$ a^1/3

So a^1/3 is fixed point

Hence by the theorem $x_n$ converges to a^1/3

Comment: Thanks, that what I had. I've also been asked to show that it converges quadratically and find the constant. I've done some googling but can't figure it out. Any ideas?